# Impersonated signing not picking up selected signature and stamps using docusignspi

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to sign a pdf file using docusignapi. I am using C# SDK from docusign to configure and create envelop.
I can see there are multiple signature can be configured in a signers account on docusign, however while adding signature tabs for a signer through c# SDK I want to control which signature from a particular signer should be used while signing the document. I am wondering how can I do that? I have similar question while using stamps as well.

Below is my code for example

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer
        {
            Email = signerEmail,
            Name = signerName,
            ClientUserId = "1000",
            RecipientId = "1"
        };
Tabs signerTabs = new Tabs { SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>() };
SignHere signHereTab = new SignHere
            {
                XPosition = signXPosition.ToString(),
                YPosition = signYposition.ToString(),
                DocumentId = reportInfo.ID.ToString(),
                PageNumber = signPageIndex.ToString(),
            };

signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs
```

when I redirect the user to their signing session, the signature they get to put is not same as what they have configured in their profile.

For example here is the signature that user has configured in their account:
[image]

Here is the signature that user is seeing during the signing ceremony:
[image]

Interesting to note is that even the GUID attached with the signature seems to be different, I guess that GUID should belong to the impersonated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen embedded signing (i.e. specified a "captive recipient" by using `clientUserId`.  Captive Recipients are never matched to DocuSign Users (users that belong to a DocuSign account). Therefore, the signer is prompted to adopt a signature the first time they sign in your embedded signing integration, and that is the new signature used anytime the same Captive Recipient (name, email, and clientUserId) is specified.

The signer's adopted signature in their DocuSign Profile is only used when they are a remote signer, not embedded.

Note: when using `clientUserId`, do not use the same value for multiple people.  Re-use the same `clientUserId` only for the same person (name and email combo).

Answer (score 0):

The signer chooses their signature. Not the sender.

The sender can choose to require the signer to authenticate (many options are available) and can require the signer to use a digital signature (AES or QES).

### Templates

Consider using a template for creating your envelope. You create a template using the graphical DocuSign web app. Then your envelope API call just refers to the templateId. Much easier than defining everything in the envelope definition.